# How to find DNS names from IP list in Powershell using a manual DNS server?

Tags: powershell, dns

So I've tried a few different solutions that I've found on Stack but none that allows for manual entry of a DNS server. My local DNS server (172.30.x.x) doesn't contain the records I'm looking for relating to IPs of 172.31.x.x or 10.x.x.x. Here is one snippet of code that works for local IPs only.

```
    $outFile = "C:\temp\hostnameresults.txt"

Get-Content C:\temp\iplist.txt | ForEach-Object {
    $hash = @{ IPAddress = $_
        hostname = "n/a"     
    }
    $hash.hostname = ([system.net.dns]::GetHostByAddress($_)).hostname
    $object = New-Object psobject -Property $hash
    Export-CSV -InputObject $object -Path $outFile -Append -NoTypeInformation
}
```

I want to query private IPs outside my local LAN by specifying a DNS server. Is this possible?

Currently, I have to use nslookup> IP> specific_dns_server to get results one IP at a time and obviously time consuming.

Comment: `I want to query private IPs outside my local LAN by specifying a DNS server` simply you can't, use `[system.net.dns]::GetHostEntry`, your local DNS cache should be updated and be faster for future queries.

Comment: I believe [`Resolve-DnsName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/dnsclient/resolve-dnsname?view=windowsserver2019-ps) can help you, see example 2.

Comment: Of course considering that `172.31.x.x` & `10.x.x.x` are private IPs I assume the DNS server is within those networks and you can reach said DNS server.